column-count causes errors with printing tables
Short version: If I use column-count in my CSS and print the page to a PDF, only the first page is printed, regardless of how much data is on the webpage.  I have been using this CSS for over 2 years, and it just recently broke.  I've tested in Chrome/Edge (v126).  It's been supported since chrome 50.
Here is an example of what the webpage should look like using the column-count.

As you can see from the scroll bar on the right, there are a lot of these tables.  If I print, it only shows one page:

Just for the heck of it, I changed the page size to letter, but it still shows one page:

For the HTML, I am using tables (using the all standard <table> tags).  They have a header and footer that are a consistent height, but the number of rows can vary.
So, I guess question 1.  Does anyone know why column-count is only allowing me to print the first page?
Question 2 Assuming I can't solve the column-count issue, how else can I get the same output?  I have tried everything that I can think of, but each fails for various other reasons.
If you look at the first screenshot, in the first column, each table starts at the end of the previous table.  In the second column, the same is happening, so the starts of the tables don't line up across columns.
I tried using Display: Flex; for example, but the starts of each table line up across columns, so there are gaps between the end of one table and the start of the next.  In a different method it would adjust the heights of the rows so that the tables are overall the same height (even if I set height:).
Thanks in advance.
EDIT: Here's a sample of the code.  Because there's so much, and I can't seem to upload a file, you'll have to copy and paste the one table in there a bunch of times (I keep hitting the char limit):
<html xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:cif="cif" xmlns:dck="dck">
<head>
<META http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="PATH TO YOUR CSS FILE\YOURCSSFILE.css">
<title lang="en">testing new css</title>
</head>
<body>
<table border="1" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
<thead>
<tr>
<th colspan="2" lang="en" valign="middle">
ASSESSMENT NUMBER
</th>
<th colspan="6" lang="en" valign="middle">
OWNERSHIP OF RECORD
</th>
<th colspan="1" lang="en" valign="middle">
TYPE OF ACQUISITION
</th>
<th colspan="1" lang="en" valign="middle">
TITLE SOURCE
</th>
<th colspan="1" lang="en" valign="middle">
PARCEL AREA (ACRES)
</th>
<th colspan="1" lang="en" valign="middle">
PAGE NUMBER
</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<th colspan="2" lang="en" valign="middle">123-11.14-34.00</th>
<th colspan="6" lang="en" valign="middle" align="left" style="text-transform:uppercase">( 1 ) Phillup McCrevice</th>
<th colspan="1" lang="en" valign="middle">R/W</th>
<th colspan="1" lang="en" valign="middle" style="text-transform:uppercase">123-456</th>
<th colspan="1" lang="en" valign="middle">D - 
0.571</th>
<th colspan="1" lang="en" valign="middle">7</th>
</tr>
<tr style="font-size: 90%">
<th lang="en" rowspan="1" valign="bottom">PT. NO.</th>
<th lang="en" rowspan="1" valign="bottom">ALIGN. NO.</th>
<th lang="en" rowspan="1" valign="bottom">STATION</th>
<th lang="en" rowspan="1" valign="bottom">OFFSET*</th>
<th lang="en" rowspan="1" valign="bottom">NORTH</th>
<th lang="en" rowspan="1" valign="bottom">EAST</th>
<th lang="en" valign="bottom">BEARING</th>
<th lang="en" valign="bottom">DISTANCE</th>
<th lang="en" valign="bottom">CHORD BEARING</th>
<th lang="en" valign="bottom">CHORD LENGTH</th>
<th lang="en" valign="bottom">ARC LENGTH</th>
<th lang="en" valign="bottom">RADIUS**</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr style="font-size: 75%">
<td class="sidepad" valign="middle" align="center" style="text-transform:uppercase">60001</td>
<td class="sidepad" align="right" nowrap valign="middle">UPTOWN ROAD</td>
<td class="sidepad" align="right" nowrap valign="middle">601+21.40</td>
<td class="sidepad" align="right" nowrap valign="middle">-25.687</td>
<td class="sidepad" align="right" valign="middle">206029.1673</td>
<td class="sidepad" align="right" valign="middle">611895.9898</td>
<td class="sidepad" align="right" nowrap valign="middle">S 88°16'50" W</td>
<td class="sidepad" align="right" valign="middle">4.637</td>
<td class="sidepad" align="right" valign="middle"> </td>
<td class="sidepad" align="right" valign="middle"> </td>
<td class="sidepad" align="right" valign="middle"> </td>
<td class="sidepad" align="right" valign="middle"> </td>
</tr>
<tr style="font-size: 75%">
<td class="sidepad" valign="middle" align="center" style="text-transform:uppercase">60106</td>
<td class="sidepad" align="right" nowrap valign="middle">UPTOWN ROAD</td>
<td class="sidepad" align="right" nowrap valign="middle">601+19.70</td>
<td class="sidepad" align="right" nowrap valign="middle">-30.000</td>
<td class="sidepad" align="right" valign="middle">206029.0282</td>
<td class="sidepad" align="right" valign="middle">611891.3548</td>
<td class="sidepad" align="right" nowrap valign="middle">N 19°49'54" E</td>
<td class="sidepad" align="right" valign="middle">247.286</td>
<td class="sidepad" align="right" valign="middle"> </td>
<td class="sidepad" align="right" valign="middle"> </td>
<td class="sidepad" align="right" valign="middle"> </td>
<td class="sidepad" align="right" valign="middle"> </td>
</tr>
<tr style="font-size: 75%">
<td class="sidepad" valign="middle" align="center" style="text-transform:uppercase">60107</td>
<td class="sidepad" align="right" nowrap valign="middle">UPTOWN ROAD</td>
<td class="sidepad" align="right" nowrap valign="middle">603+66.99</td>
<td class="sidepad" align="right" nowrap valign="middle">-30.000</td>
<td class="sidepad" align="right" valign="middle">206261.6491</td>
<td class="sidepad" align="right" valign="middle">611975.2483</td>
<td class="sidepad" align="right" valign="middle"> </td>
<td class="sidepad" align="right" valign="middle"> </td>
<td class="sidepad" align="right" nowrap valign="middle">N 19°42'50" E</td>
<td class="sidepad" align="right" nowrap valign="middle">16.300</td>
<td class="sidepad" align="right" nowrap valign="middle">16.300</td>
<td class="sidepad" align="right" nowrap valign="middle">
-
3970.000</td>
</tr>
<tr style="font-size: 75%">
<td class="sidepad" valign="middle" align="center" style="text-transform:uppercase">60108</td>
<td class="sidepad" align="right" nowrap valign="middle">UPTOWN ROAD</td>
<td class="sidepad" align="right" nowrap valign="middle">603+83.41</td>
<td class="sidepad" align="right" nowrap valign="middle">-30.000</td>
<td class="sidepad" align="right" valign="middle">206276.9935</td>
<td class="sidepad" align="right" valign="middle">611980.7466</td>
<td class="sidepad" align="right" nowrap valign="middle">N 66°47'22" E</td>
<td class="sidepad" align="right" valign="middle">5.568</td>
<td class="sidepad" align="right" valign="middle"> </td>
<td class="sidepad" align="right" valign="middle"> </td>
<td class="sidepad" align="right" valign="middle"> </td>
<td class="sidepad" align="right" valign="middle"> </td>
</tr>
<tr style="font-size: 75%">
<td class="sidepad" valign="middle" align="center" style="text-transform:uppercase">60003</td>
<td class="sidepad" align="right" nowrap valign="middle">UPTOWN ROAD</td>
<td class="sidepad" align="right" nowrap valign="middle">603+87.22</td>
<td class="sidepad" align="right" nowrap valign="middle">-25.913</td>
<td class="sidepad" align="right" valign="middle">206279.1878</td>
<td class="sidepad" align="right" valign="middle">611985.8637</td>
<td class="sidepad" align="right" nowrap valign="middle">S 19°46'18" W</td>
<td class="sidepad" align="right" valign="middle">0.226</td>
<td class="sidepad" align="right" valign="middle"> </td>
<td class="sidepad" align="right" valign="middle"> </td>
<td class="sidepad" align="right" valign="middle"> </td>
<td class="sidepad" align="right" valign="middle"> </td>
</tr>
<tr style="font-size: 75%">
<td class="sidepad" valign="middle" align="center" style="text-transform:uppercase">60002</td>
<td class="sidepad" align="right" nowrap valign="middle">UPTOWN ROAD</td>
<td class="sidepad" align="right" nowrap valign="middle">603+86.99</td>
<td class="sidepad" align="right" nowrap valign="middle">-25.914</td>
<td class="sidepad" align="right" valign="middle">206278.9754</td>
<td class="sidepad" align="right" valign="middle">611985.7874</td>
<td class="sidepad" align="right" nowrap valign="middle">S 19°46'18" W</td>
<td class="sidepad" align="right" valign="middle">265.458</td>
<td class="sidepad" align="right" valign="middle"> </td>
<td class="sidepad" align="right" valign="middle"> </td>
<td class="sidepad" align="right" valign="middle"> </td>
<td class="sidepad" align="right" valign="middle"> </td>
</tr>
<tr style="font-size: 75%">
<td class="sidepad" valign="middle" align="center" style="text-transform:uppercase">60001</td>
<td class="sidepad" align="right" nowrap valign="middle">UPTOWN ROAD</td>
<td class="sidepad" align="right" nowrap valign="middle">601+21.40</td>
<td class="sidepad" align="right" nowrap valign="middle">-25.687</td>
<td class="sidepad" align="right" valign="middle">206029.1673</td>
<td class="sidepad" align="right" valign="middle">611895.9898</td>
<td class="sidepad" align="right" valign="middle"> </td>
<td class="sidepad" align="right" valign="middle"> </td>
<td class="sidepad" align="right" valign="middle"> </td>
<td class="sidepad" align="right" valign="middle"> </td>
<td class="sidepad" align="right" valign="middle"> </td>
<td class="sidepad" align="right" valign="middle"> </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
<tfoot>
<tr>
<th colspan="12" lang="en" valign="middle" align="left">
FIGURE 40000　　AREA = 1105.30 SQ. FT. (0.025 ACRES).　　
<br>
REMAINING AREA = 23767.46 SQ. FT. (  0.546 ACRES)　　
<br>
CUMULATIVE REMAINING AREA = 23767.46 SQ.FT (
0.546 ACRES)
</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<th colspan="12" lang="en" valign="middle" align="left" style="text-transform:uppercase">
DEED RECORD OF ACQUISITION: </th>
</tr>
</tfoot>
</table>
</body>
</html>

EDIT:  Also, here's my CSS
body
{
column-count: 2;
column-width: 50%;
font-size: 10pt;
color: #000000;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica;
background-color: #ffffff
}
table
{
break-inside: avoid;
border-left-color: #000000;
border-bottom-color: #000000;
font-size: 10pt;
color: #000000;
border-top-color: #000000;
font-style: normal;
font-family: arial;
border-right-color: #000000;
table-border-color-light: #000000;
table-border-color-dark: #000000
}
table.margin
{
margin-left: .5in
}
caption
{
font-size: 14pt;
color: #666633;
font-style: normal;
font-family: arial
}
th
{
border-left-color: #000000;
border-bottom-color: #000000;
color: #000000;
border-top-color: #000000;
font-style: normal;
font-family: arial;
border-right-color: #000000
}


Are you sur it is column-count the problem? Did you try without it? Also, could we have some code that reproduces the bug you see so we can test/try

I think you are going to need to show us relevant code, perhaps create a simple version which has two pages and which definitely shows the problem, otherwise any answer will be a guess. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

If I comment out the column-count line within the CSS it will print all the pages.  It obv just won't be in two columns.  I'll prep the HTML and post it in a minute.  Sorry about that.

Ok, I uploaded a sample of the code.   I could only put in one table and I didn't want to strip the data from that one table as it might mess up formatting.  Should be easy enough to copy and paste that one table a ton of times.  Original one has 61 tables in it.

Without knowing absolutely all the context of your code, it's difficult to be absolutely sure, but it seems that the problem is caused by the fact that your site is working in Quirks mode as there is no !doctype given at the top.
Place this right at the top:
<!doctype html>

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Quirks_Mode_and_Standards_Mode
I have tested on Windows11 Edge with and without the !doctype and with it the printer showed all pages. I tested with a couple of dozen tables and ensured the last one was included by setting its text color: red

Wow.  Thankyou.  I would probably have never found that.   Thank you so much for your time and patience.
